# PropertyTypeException in Apache Tika Metadata

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm using Crawler4j to extract pages and pdf files. I already checked that the byte array I got is valid and can be output to a pdf file.

With this byte array, I do the following:

```
//Tika specific types
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
InputStream inputstream;
ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser();

...

byte[] contentData = null;
contentData = page.getContentData(); //Crawler4j content, delivers valid PDF
//Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Test\\local.pdf"); //use this line to read from a local pdf

//Default fields:
String title = "pdf title";
String content = "";
String suggestions = "";
//
try {
    ////contentData = Files.readAllBytes(path); //use this line to read from a local pdf
    inputstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentData);
    pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata,pcontext); //THIS LINE CRASHES
    content = "pdf suggestions";
    suggestions = handler.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.warn("Error parsing with Tika.", e);
}
```

I marked the crashing line. The resulting Exception is the following:

`WARN    2017-07-26 11:17:51,302 [Thread-5] de.searchadapter.crawler.solrparser.parser.file.PDFFileParser  - Error parsing with Tika.
org.apache.tika.metadata.PropertyTypeException: xmpMM:DocumentID : SIMPLE
    at org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata.add(Metadata.java:305)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.image.xmp.JempboxExtractor.addMetadata(JempboxExtractor.java:209)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.image.xmp.JempboxExtractor.extractXMPMM(JempboxExtractor.java:150)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.extractMetadata(PDFParser.java:239)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:154)
    at de.searchadapter.crawler.solrparser.parser.file.PDFFileParser.parse(PDFFileParser.java:82)
    at de.searchadapter.crawler.solrparser.SolrParser.parse(SolrParser.java:36)
    at de.searchadapter.crawler.SolrJAdapter.indexDocs(SolrJAdapter.java:58)
    at de.searchadapter.crawler.WebCrawler.onBeforeExit(WebCrawler.java:63)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlController$1.run(CrawlController.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

The code above is from the `PDFFileParser`. I'm not setting any property, so I'm puzzled where this error comes from.

Additional info: The PDF file seems to use an unknown font, the following warning comes up:

`11:17:50.963 [Thread-5] WARN  o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont - No Unicode mapping for f_i (30) in font GGOLOE+TheSansC5-Plain`

**EDIT:** I edited the code, so that it could read local pdf files. I tried another PDF file and didn't get the error. It seems like it results of the failing font.

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I am using same issue, and i am using latest Apache Tika version i.e. 1.16

Comment: @Yogi ugh... this problem :D

Comment: I'm seeing the same `org.apache.tika.metadata.PropertyTypeException: xmpMM:DocumentID : SIMPLE` any luck resolving this issue?

Comment: @bachr long since I've been on this topic. But my guess would still be a failing font. Sadly I can't recall any resolve for this